# If you are doing an ONIOM calculation in Gaussian, how do you add both custom MM parameters and a custom basis set using GEN and Amber=SoftFirst?

Tags: quantum-chemistry, computational-chemistry, basis-set

I am trying to calculate a biological system using AMBER forcefields as my low-layer in ONIOM3. I also want to use a non-native basis set (aug-pc-1 for opt+freq, aug-pc-2 for SPE) that requires custom input.

Using ONIOM(M062X/gen:amber=softfirst) gives me syntax errors and errors in RdPar.

How do I resolve this?

Gaussian documentation provides no resolution, and google provides no answer either!

Comment: I suspect that many Gaussian experts hang out over at Matter Modeling SE (https://mattermodeling.stackexchange.com/)

Answer (score 1):

I've decided to troubleshoot the issue presented earlier, and feel it might benefit others to spare them the headaches through an easily google-able problem.

**If using JUST the gen keyword...**

After the connectivity table, leave exactly 1 empty line before pasting the specification from Basis set exchange. End the input file with exactly 2 empty lines.

**If using JUST the Amber=SoftFirst keyword,**

After the connectivity table, leave exactly 2 empty line before pasting your custom AMBER parameters. If you have custom non-bonding parameters, they must be flush with the rest of the parameter specification. Any line within the parameter specification that is preceded by an extra space will cause syntax errors.

**If using BOTH,** (ergo: ONIOM(m062x/gen:amber) amber=softfirst

After the connectivity table, leave EXACTLY 2 empty lines, THEN FIRST input the molecule mechanics parameters as above.

AFTER the last line of the molecule mechanics parameter specification, leave EXACTLY 1 empty line, THEN input the gaussian formatted basis set from Basis Set Exchange, and leave EXACTLY 2 empty lines at the end of the input file.

I hope it helps others avoid headaches!